# Animating a View in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I've been trying to animate a UIView with a spring animation using swift. I am able to achieve it when I use objective C, however I get an error in swift. This is the animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3,
usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
initialSpringVelocity: 3.0,
animations:{
viewToAnimate.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: 100.0)},
completion: nil)
```

The compiler gives me an error saying

```
Could not find an overload for 'animateWithDuration' that accepts supplied arguments.
```

If I delete the "usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
initialSpringVelocity: 3.0," it compiles and animated fine. How can I make the spring animation in swift?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're missing a parameter. The method also takes a delay as input.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: ({
    // do stuff
}), completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [], animations: 
{
    self.yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
}, completion: nil)
```